# Implementing an asynchronous mutex in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety

I wrote a simple synchronization primitive that I can use with async operations on an external REST service so that I don't call it twice from different threads and have one call fail due to not having the latest state. Despite obvious limitations of *that* design decision I think this should solve my problem...

```
struct DumbAsyncMutex
{
    int busy;

    public async Task WithMutexAsync(Func<Task> t)
    {
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref busy, 1, 0) != 0)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }

        try
        {
            await t();
        }
        finally
        {
            while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref busy, 0, 1) != 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Releasing the mutex failed - but this should never happen");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this is a hack... did I just overlook a better way to do this using the standard framework?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A better alternative to the busy wait loop would be to use a Semaphore - in this case a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would probably be the most appropriate. Semaphores are not reentrant. This would simplify the implementation to:

```
struct DumbAsyncMutex
{
    private SemaphoreSlim _Semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    public async Task WithMutexAsync(Func<Task> t)
    {
        await _Semaphore.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            await t();
        }
        finally
        {
            _Semaphore.Release(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage is that it has `async` support and you can abandon the waiting by using cancellation tokens.

Comment: Great answer. SemaphoreSlim mostly makes DumbAsyncMutex redundant. But one disadvantage I found to this is that SemaphoreSlim is IDisposable (which can lead to lotsa code analysis warnings).

Comment: @TimLovell-Smith: Hm true, this means that `DumbAsyncMutex` should be `IDisposable` as well since it's owning the semaphore. So you need to make sure to dispose the mutex object properly in all cases (which in turn means any object owning one of these mutexes needs to be `IDisposable` as well)

Comment: Did some diving... it does seem probably safe to ignore the IDisposable code analyis warnings SemaphoreSlim.Dispose doesn't seem to have any effect unless you are using the AvailableWaitHandle property, and here you're wrapping the semaphore so you know that won't happen.

Answer (score 2):

### Naming

The following qoute from [Naming Guidelines on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx) is one of my favorites:

> The goal of this chapter is to provide a consistent set of naming
>   conventions that results in names that make immediate sense to
>   developers.

There are a couple of alternative names that I can suggest:

- The name `DumbAsyncMutex` is confusing because

  1. The type it represents is not a mutex at all
  2. An asynchronous mutex does not make sense
  3. It can be changed to `TaskExecutionSynchronizer`
  4. I think the latter describes the funtion of the type way better because the type simply "synchronizes execution of tasks"
- The method name `WithMutexAsync` is not a good name and can be changed to `QueueTask` because that is what this method actually does, queueing tasks for synchronized execution.
- The name `busy` makes sense but

  1. It sounds too broad to represent a flag used for synchronization
  2. It's name can be changed to `numberOfTasksInProgress`.
  3. Yes, this will change the meaning of the variable from being a flag to being an integer counting ongoing parallel executions
  4. But we limit it's values to 1 or 0 anyway so it should be fine. (The number of parallel executions is either 1 or 0)
- The parameter name `t`

  1. Is `t`
  2. It can at least be changed to `task`.
  3. You can use your creativity to name it better, unfortunately mine refused to co-operate for a name like `t`

### Functionality

- It is very likely that the tasks registered to execute (by `await
  WithMutexAsync()` call) will not be executed in the same order. This
  may or may not cause an issue, I don't know the full flow.
- That is, if a call to this method is made while a previous call is
  waiting at Task.Delay() and the mutex at that moment is released
  (busy = 0) during that delay, the latest passed `Task` will be
  executed instantly while the previously passed `Task` will wait for
  this one's execution as well. This actually introduces a FIGKWIOF
  type of queue. (First In God Knows Which Is Out First).
- Another important point is, you cannot pass the instance of this
  struct around to ensure synchronized execution of REST service calls
  because it is a value type (`struct`) and the value of the field
  `busy` will be copied and `Task`s passed into that new instance will
  lost the synchronization context with the `Task`s executed by the
  original instance. You can overcome this by changing the type to a `class`.
- Apart from that, the use of `Interlocked.CompareExchange` for this
  purpose feels like kind of abuse. Why don't you instead use
  `Monitor.TryEnter` without a timeout?
- Also, the `while` loop in the `finally` block seems completely
  unnecessary (is it a result of a copy/paste?). You can achieve the
  same behaviour by an `if` statement.

Comment: I'm not using Monitor.TryEnter because of a functional issue - its thread reentrant locking.

Comment: Re 'An asynchronous mutex does not make sense'
- And oh but it does. It's achieving 'mutual exclusion'. ;-) I like your feedback on functionality though!

Answer (score 1):

I see one possible problem with this approach namely that any exception (except for a `ThreadAbortException`) which is maybe thrown by the `Func<Task> t` is silently swallowed if the mutex couldn't be freed.

See: [what happens if a finally block throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2911229/2655508)

A possible workaround could be to have a `catch` block which stores the exception in a variable which is later passed as an innerexception to the `new Exception`.

---

The naming of the `struct` and the method parameter is not very good, because it doesn't tell a reader of the code anything about it. Try to use better names.